# crontab not producing the required result

Tags: linux, centos, cron

]# crontab -l

```
#ROOT CRONTAB test

#22 15 * * * root my_date=`date +\%Y-\%m-\%0e_\%H:\%M:\%S`; /usr/bin/pg_dumpall -U postgres > /home/apache/tactic_backup/postgresDb_${my_date}
53 13 * * * root /home/apache/tactic_custom_tools/backup.sh
```

]# more /home/apache/tactic_custom_tools/backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash                                                               
/usr/bin/pg_dumpall -U postgres > /home/apache/tactic_backup/postgresDb/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%0e_\%H:\%M:\%S
```

It doesn't create anything under /home/apache/tactic_backup/postgresDb/

But when i run the script or command as root, it works and does the required. But via crontab it doesn't The crontab above is for root. Even in logs it shows that it ran(or so)

```
Jan 28 13:40:01 bjweb01 crond[13935]: (root) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/root)
Jan 28 13:40:01 bjweb01 CROND[34555]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jan 28 13:40:01 bjweb01 CROND[34556]: (root) CMD (root /home/apache/tactic_custom_tools/backup.sh)
Jan 28 13:46:47 bjweb01 crontab[34743]: (root) LIST (root)
Jan 28 13:49:53 bjweb01 crontab[34814]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Jan 28 13:50:01 bjweb01 CROND[34818]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jan 28 13:52:11 bjweb01 crontab[34814]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Jan 28 13:52:11 bjweb01 crontab[34814]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Jan 28 13:53:01 bjweb01 crond[13935]: (root) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/root)
Jan 28 13:53:01 bjweb01 CROND[34887]: (root) CMD (root /home/apache/tactic_custom_tools/backup.sh)
```

Any idea what i am missing?

Comment: Would it be possible that `pg_dumpall` needs the `postgres` parameter to be given with full path?

Comment: pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": FATAL:  role "root" does not exist


you get this

Comment: You get this when you try with full path or when you try with `/usr/bin/pg_dumpall -U postgres`? I would try to add a `touch /tmp/testfile` in the script to see if the script is being executed. This way you can see exactly where is the problem.

Comment: its just like my script, its /usr/bin/pg_dumpall -U postgres > /home/apache/tactic_backup/postgresDb/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%0e_\%H:\%M:\%S   

 
the script works and creates the file when manually run on the shell as root, but not via crontab

Comment: Strange. Have you tried giving the path of the binary to execute the script? `* * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: yes, if you see my post, i have shown the o/p of root's crontab, i tried both ways, as a script and as a command. no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My documentation states that the mentioning of the user (`root` in this case) after the time restrictions is only valid in the system crontab which is stored at `/etc/crontab`.

You are showing us users' crontabs (shown with `crontab -l`) which differ in that aspect; the user must not be given there, even if the user is root.

Comment: so i should add it to /etc/crontab or crontab -u root -e ? i want this to just take a backup. i thought root crontab was safer. and what actually calls /etc/crontab, which user?

Comment: I would not change the system crontab, no, unless you think that your change is part of the operating system (doesn't sound like this, no).  So just create a crontab for user root (I think you already have) and leave out those wrong mentions of the user after the time specification.

Comment: thank you, that worked. removing the "root" from the crontab